# Codeigniter Routing Not Rewriting the url

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I am not much expert in codeigniter routing, but i need to rewrite/mask the url

my actual url is
**example.com/america/newyork/200/OC/2015/DALL/CALL**

Where **200/OC/2015/DALL/CALL** is values which i am passing in that page

I want to mask the url something like this
**example.com/america/newyork/**

what i actually done

```
$route['default_controller'] = "america";
$route['america/newyork/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'america/newyork/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5';
```

but the above routing seems to be not working of what i expected , may i can know where i making mistake

Here is my newyork method

```
public function newyork($one='',$two='',$three='',$four='',$five='')
    {
        echo $one.''.$two.''.$three.''.$four.''.$five;
    }
```

Comment: Trying this`$route['america/newyork/(:any)'] = 'america/newyork/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5';`

Comment: Not working @KevinYan

Comment: Can you paste your `newyork ` method and the access result on?

Comment: i posted newyork method above

Comment: You got a 404 error, or...  ? @musthafa

Comment: No i am not getting any error but page url is not masking , if i access example.com/america/newyork/200/OC/2015/DALL/CALL, it is still the same url , but i want show url as example.com/america/newyork/

Comment: Oh, I don't think you can't achieve this by  route!

Comment: oh then it means my question is worng, what is the right way to achieve it

Comment: Thanks kevin i got another way of working it , anyway thanks  for your help

Comment: If you've found the answer, either check this one as accepted or post your answer and mark it as accepted. Others finding this post need to see the resolution.

Comment: But i didnt find the solution of masking i find different solution which is not related to this post itself which is based on my code

Answer (score 0):

Beyond an ID, I've never been able to get CI to load anything from the URL without manually specifying it in the method. So it's probably not going to automatically pull your $one, $two, et cetera.

But if you load the URI segments in your function (probably not the most efficient way of doing it), maybe you'll get some results.

```
$one = $this->uri->segment(whatever_segment_number_here);
```

This does, of course, require that you autoload the URL helper or load it on-demand in your method.